# Show that an increasing function has derivative $0$ a.e.

Tags: probability, measure-theory, radon-nikodym

Let $0<p<1$ and define $F:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ by $$F(x)=\begin{cases}
pF(2x),&x\in\left[0,\frac12\right]\\
p+qF(2x-1),&x\in\left[\frac12,1\right]
\end{cases}$$
where $q=1-p$.  I would like to prove that $F'(x)=0$ a.e.

I am working my way through ["How to Gamble If You Must"](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/joma/Volume8/Siegrist/RedBlack.pdf) by Kyle Siegerst, which is basically a series of exercises.  $F(x)$ is the probability that a gambler starting with a bankroll $0\leq x\leq 1$ will reach his target of $1$ if he engages in "bold play" in the game of red and black.  When his bankroll is $\leq\frac12$ he bets it all, winning the amount bet with probability $p$, and losing it with probability $q$.  When his bankroll is $>\frac12$, he bets just enough to reach the target, that is, $1-x$.

In the exercises, I have shown that there is a unique function $F$ satisfying the functional equation above, and that it is continuous and strictly increasing.  Following exercise $33$, the author remarks that when $p\neq\frac12$, $F'(X)=0$ a.e., so that $F$ is a devil's staircase.  I have been trying to prove this statement.  (I know that an increasing function is differentiable a.e.  It's the value that I'm having trouble with.)

Vague $50$-year-old memories of measure theory have led me to Proposition 3.31 in Folland's "Real Analysis", to wit

If $F\in NBV, \text{ then }F\in L^1(m).$  Moreover, $\mu_F\perp m \text{ iff } F' =0$ a.e., and $\mu_F \ll m \text{ iff } F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^xF'(t)dt. $

Here $m$ is Lebesgue measure, and a.e. is with respect to Lebesgue measure.  $\mu_F$ is the Borel measure defined by $\mu_F([a,b])=F(b)-F(a)$.  Folland uses $NBV$ to mean that $F$ is of bounded variation, $F(-\infty)=0$ and $F$ is right continuous.  This is no problem, as we can extend $F$ to $\mathbb{R}$ by defining $F(x)=0$ for $x<0$ and $F(x)=1$ for $x>1$.

So it seems to come down to showing $\mu_F\perp m$.  This means that there is an  $E\subset[0,1]$ with $m(E)=0$ and $\mu_F(E)=1$ if I'm not mistaken.  I don't see how to prove this.  Indeed it doesn't seem at all likely to me, so I must misunderstand something.

In exercise 29, I proved that $$F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty p_{x_1}\cdots p_{x_{n-1}}px_n$$ where $x_i$ is bit number $i$ of $x$, and $p_0=p,\ p_1=q$.  (When $x$ is a dyadic rational, we take the terminating representation.)   If we represent wins by $1$ and losses by $0$, this means that the gambler reaches the goal if and only if the first time a bit in his bankroll matches the corresponding game bit, those bits are both $1$.  This is the most concrete representation of $F$ in the paper, but I don't see how it helps.

Can you cast any light on this for me?

Comment: You probably found this already: I _think_ for $x \in (0, 1/2)$ we have $F'(x) = 2p F'(2x)$ and for $x \in (1/2, 1)$ we have $F'(x) = 2q F'(2x - 1)$.  Can something be made from this?

Comment: @antkam Thanks, but I don't think so.  When $p=\frac12$, we have that $F(x)=x$ satisfies the functional equation, and oof course the derivative satisfies the equations you give.  Of course in this case, it isn't true that $f'(x0=0$.

Comment: Sure, I implicitly meant "can something be made from this _assuming_ $p \neq 1/2$" :)

Comment: In my understanding exercise 33 already shows $\mu_F \perp m$. It is argued via ex 26 and 27 that $F$ is the cdf of the random variable $W$ - so $\mu_F(A) = P(W \in A)$. Then exercise 33 constructs a family of sets $C_p$ such that $P_p(W \in C_t) = \mathbf{1}\{p = t\}$, and in particular this shows that $m(C_p) = P_{1/2}(W \in C_p) = 0, \mu_{F_p}(C_p) = P_p( W \in C_p) = 1$ for any $p \neq 1/2.$ Is your actual question to solve one or more of ex 26,27,33? Or do you want a more direct approach?

Comment: @stochasticboy321 I second your comment (was about to write it as an answer but then saw you just posted this comment)

Comment: Possibly a stupid question, but here goes: What's wrong with the following proof(?) that one does not have $F'(x) = 0$ almost everywhere? Assuming $F'(x) = 0$ almost everywhere, one has $\int_0^1 F'(x) \, dx = 0$ (Lebesgue integral), but at the same time the integral equals $F(1) - F(0) = 1 - 0 = 1$.

Comment: @primes.against.humanity the reason is the fundamental theorem of calculus fails for this function. You should look up the devils staircase

Comment: @shalop I mentioned in the question that I proved in the exercises that there is a unique function $F$ that satisfies the functional equation and that it is continuous and strictly increasing.

Comment: Oh right, thanks. @saulspatz

Comment: @stochasticboy321 No, I was able to prove all the exercises.  I just didn't really see the significance of exercise 33.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that $F$ is the cdf of the random variable $X:=\sum_1^{\infty} 2^{-n} \xi_n$ where the $\xi_n$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli$(p)$ random variables. Indeed, it is clear that that $X = \frac12\xi_1+\frac12 Y$, where $Y$ has the same distribution as $X$ and is independent of $\xi_1$. This gives the relation $$P(X\le x) = P(X\le x|\xi_1=0)P(\xi_1=0)+P(X \le x|\xi_1=1)P(\xi_1=1) $$$$= (pP(Y\leq 2x)+q\cdot 0)1_{\{x \le 1/2\}} + (p\cdot 1 +qP(Y\leq 2x-1))1_{\{x >1/2\}},$$ which is exactly the relation for $F$.

Now note by the strong law of large numbers that $X$ is supported on the set of real numbers whose binary expansion has asymptotic density $p$ of $1$'s (or equivalently, has asymptotic density $q$ of $0$'s).

But the set of all such real numbers has Lebesgue measure zero. Indeed, if we uniformly sample a real number from $[0,1]$, then its binary digits are i.i.d. Bernoulli$(1/2)$, thus almost surely the asymptotic density of $1$'s is $1/2$, not $p$.

We conclude that the law of $X$ is singular with respect to Lebesgue measure, which is equivalent to the condition that $F'=0$ a.e..

Comment: Additional fun fact: by induction on $n$, it is easy to show that $\big|F\big((k+1)2^{-n}\big)-F\big(k2^{-n}\big)\big|\leq \alpha^n$ for all $n,k\ge 0$ where $\alpha := \max\{p,1-p\}$. From this, it follows by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1713724/holder-continuity/) that $F$ is Hölder continuous of exponent $|\log_2\alpha|$. Moreover this is optimal since $F(2^{-n}) = p^{n}$ and $F(1-2^{-n}) = 1-q^{n}.$